# Linux server update

Tags: linux, mysql, apache-http-server, php5

I know that for security reasons the server services have to be up to date, and since my server was attacked by a virus I think this a good time to upgrade the system.
Linux sytem:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny)
Release:    5.0.10
```

This is my server services versions:

```
apache/2.2.9 (debian) 
php/5.2.6-1+lenny16 with suhosin-patch 
mod_python/3.3.1 python/2.5.2 
mod_ssl/2.2.9 
openssl/0.9.8g 
mod_perl/2.0.4 perl/v5.10.0
```

The question is what HAVE TO BE upgraded and which version is required, I'am not sure if a version I am gonna use is stable or not, this is why Iam asking this question.
Do I need to update the debian version too? What risks can I experience?

Answer (score 2):

Security updates for your version of Debian (lenny) have been discontinued as of February 6th, 2012.

Source: http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/

So you will also need to update to Debian 6 (squeeze) at least.

To upgrade:

1. backup all your data and configuration
2. Update package repositories:

   ```
   deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free 
   deb-src http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free 
   deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main 
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main 
   deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main 
   deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main
   ```
3. Fetch new repositories for Lenny

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
4. First upgrade all your packages:

   ```
   apt-get upgrade
   ```
5. Then do dist-upgrade:

   ```
   apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

More info: http://www.howtoforge.com/upgrade-debian-lenny-to-squeeze-in-a-few-simple-steps

Comment: This won't work, seeing as the lenny repositories have been down for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Lenny hasn't gotten a security update since February 2012, and repositories have been officially discontinued.

Without a clear upgrade path, as well as being two versions behind, the easiest way out is probably making backups of everything you need and installing Debian 7.0, Wheezy.

Keeping your system updated is extremely important, and it's short of a wonder you've only gotten infected once.